# For which values of $x$ is $f(x)$ defined? For this function:

Tags: functions

The function in question here is:
$$
f(x) = 6 \ln{(x + 2)} − x^{2}
$$

I can see that if $x$ is greater than $-2$ the function will be defined, but how can I say this for certain? Also, in other questions where it is not easy to spot this, is there a way to work it out mathematically?

Comment: what is $x(x)$?

Comment: x times x i.e. x^2 . But that is the way it is represented in the question.

Comment: you just said it for certain, didn't you ? Formally $\ln t$ is defined for $t>0$ so taking $t=x+2>0$ solving for $x$ we get $x>-2$. Since $x^2$ is always defined, the only restriction is $x>2$.

Comment: I understand but say for example we had a more complicated natural log or something different like: a trigonometric function + a hyperbolic function how would you do it then?

Comment: Thanks I will from now on.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is: For $f(g(x))$ to be defined we need $g(x)$ to be defined at $x$ and that $f$ is defined at $g(x)$.  Of course, we have the following basic rules (for real functions):

- $a(x)+b(x),a(x)-b(x),a(x)\cdot b(x)$ are always defined (provided $a(x),b(x)$ are, of course)
- $\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$ is defined only if $b(x)\ne 0$.
- $\sin(x),\cos(x),\exp(x)$ are defined for all $x$
- $\sqrt{x}$ is defined only if $x\ge 0$ (but $\sqrt[3]x$ for all $x$)
- $\ln(x)$ is defined only for $x>0$

We can reduce $\tan x$ to $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, which is defined only if $\cos x\ne 0$, i.e., if $x$ is not an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$. This example already shows that things can become quite complicated in combination.
For example in order to investigate where $\sqrt{\ln(e^x+\tan(x^2))}$ is defined one would have to solve some awful equalities and  inequalities (i.e., first: where is $\tan(x^2)$ defined? And then: where is $e^x+\tan(x^2)>0$? And finally: Where is $\ln(e^x+\tan(x^2)\ge0$? Actually, the last two can be combined into: Where is $e^x+\tan(x^2)\ge1$? But that does not allow a closed from description either ...)